# Is there a shortcut in Visual Studio Code to make a class selector from clicking on class attribute?

Tags: html, css

Are there any shortcuts in Visual Studio Code where if I click on the class attribute of the element in the html file it’ll make that class selector ready in the .css file? For instance, I right click on `class="green"` and it’d make something like the bottom in the .css file?

```html
<div class="green">I am green</div>
```

```css
.green {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it would also automatically add new selectors to your css file if they don't exist but 'CSS Peek' does allow you to quickly go to the selector.

Adding new selectors always on the bottom the css file is probably not desired in most cases since you'd want to structure your file in some way.